# how to filter data from given date in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am creating a search system in my project.  I have a "product" table and in that table I have a date field that holds values like '2015-05-13'. In my system I have two date pickers to be used to select the two dates to search between like: `From:2015-05-02 To:2015-05-14`.

I am trying to create a query based off of the dates that were chosen, and I am having issues trying to do this.  Can someone please explain how to do this?

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM `product`
 BETWEEN '2013-04-05' AND '2013-05-05'
```

Comment: Any luck figuring this one out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two ways :

```
SELECT * FROM `product` where your_date_column  BETWEEN '2013-04-05' AND '2013-05-05'

SELECT * FROM `product` where your_date_column >= '2013-04-05' AND your_date_column < = '2013-05-05';
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query is not working is because you forgot to include a `WHERE` clause. While it's not required, many MySQL queries use it. The format of a typical query may be:

```
SELECT [columns]
FROM [table]
WHERE [condition]
```

You are not only jumping straight to the condition, but you do not specify what field should be `BETWEEN` those dates. You can rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN '2013-04-05' AND '2015-05-05';
```

---

For reference, you can see this page regarding the [`SELECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h09t6a82(v=vs.80).aspx) command. They have a good example of all of the possible clauses you can add to your statement. This is a summary of the main ones:

```
SELECT Select_List
   FROM Table_List
   [WITH (BUFFERING = lExpr)]
   [WHERE Conditions]
   [GROUP BY Column_List]
   [UNION Clause]
   [HAVING Conditions]
   [ORDER BY Column_List]
   [INTO Clause | TO Clause ] 
   [Additional_Display_Options]
```

Answer (score -1):

You're pretty close:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE datefieldname BETWEEN '2013-04-05' AND '2013-05-05'
```